# How to match everything up to the last occurence of a special character set?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to modify my regex splitter.

My expression is simple: match one or more occurences of a characterset: `\s*[|()!=\s]+`

Running over this example would give:

```
(output !==(not output)) | (output)
//output, not output, output
```

Now I want the following: "if a `=` character occures, then behind match everything behind up to the last occurence of again the same character set."

Again looking at the example above, it can see the first `=`, and should then match the following completely: `!==(not output)) | (`

How could this be done?

Comment: Why should go only to the `(` and not all the way to `)` (which is really the last occurrence of one of the given characters)?

Comment: Well it's just an example. All I want to achieve is, as written above:  "if a `=` character occures, then match everything behind up to the last occurence of again the same character set." So that it takes the whole string of `=(not output)) | (`

Comment: Little improvement: In `\s*[|()!=\s]+` you don't need `\s*` at start since it is already included in `[|()!=\s]`. Maybe you wanted `\s+`?

Comment: @membersound maybe it's just an example, but it simply doesn't follow your description. If I give you a regex for "if a `=` character occures, then match everything behind up to the last occurence of again the same character set.", it will match all the way to the last `)`. So I think the specification is a bit shady here.

Comment: Yes ok, probably my specification is not correct. Maybe I should write: if a `=` occures, then skip the end of the character set one time (so that `not output` is taken), and then go to the last character occurence of the set, which is `(` before output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you mean for later use but for your current input it works

```
String data = "(output !==(not output)) | (output)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*(?=!?==)(.*)\\1").matcher(data);
//                           ^-group1          ^   ^-repeated group1
//                                             |group 2
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));//match from group 2
}
```

output:

```
!==(not output)) | (
```